# Python - Mirror parts of a list every n items

Tags: python, list, arduino, hex, reverse

i am using .xbm files to upload an image in hex format to my ESP32 to display it on an e-paper display.

The raw code looks like this (after i formated it a little):

```
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XF8,0XFF,0XFF,
0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0XFF,0X1F,
```

My problem is that for some reason, it seems that GIMP is exporting every 8-bit part of this Hex code "inverted" - in the end, apparently every 8-pixel wide column is mirrored.

(refer to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53332/waveshare-display-on-esp32-has-weird-graphic-glitches) post i made to describe the problem)

My question is now - if i have a the code as above, how can i "mirror" each row?
To clarify, i want this:
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,`

be turned into

`8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,
h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a,`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
def invert_block(block):
    inverted_block_list = []
    for row in block.split("\n"):
        inverted_row = ",".join(reversed(row.strip(",").split(",")))
        inverted_block_list.append(inverted_row)
    return "\n".join(inverted_block_list)
```

Comment: thanks, how do i use this exactly? is the "block" argument the file name of the block to be reversed?

Comment: ah yes i got it, thanks - can you think of a quick fix so that the commas are *not* reversed?  because with your solution, `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,` turns into `,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` and not `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,`

Comment: just change inverted_row = ",".join(reversed(row.strip(",").split(","))) to 
inverted_row = "".join(reversed(row.strip(",").split(","))).join(",")